# Group index values based on other index values in pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have a data frame with following structure

```
                     Sentence                 Label

A              B   
"unique ID1"   0    "Sample sentence 1"        jt
"unique ID1"   1   "Sample sentence 2"        jt  
"unique ID3"   2   "Sample sentence 3"        edu
"unique ID3"   3   "Sample sentence 4"        edu
```

I want to be able to get all values of index `B` grouped by value of index `A` where `label == jt` and repeat that for all unique label values. The preferred return type is `key-value` pairs but any other appropriate format would also work.

### Valid Example for label == jt:

`("unique ID1" : [0,1] )`

### Valid Example for label == edu:

`("unique ID3" : [2,3] )`

I already tried many `SO` questions, but haven't found what I'm looking for precisely.

I also tried this:

```py
sorted_index_df = df.sort_index(inplace = False)

multi_index = sorted_index_df.loc[sorted_index_df["label"] == "jt"].index
```

Doing that would return each value of index `A` with it's corresponding value of index `B` as a separate tuple.

Ex: `('Labor_&_Delivery_Nurse-APRN__Lidia_Lambert__', 17)`

But I want to be able to group all values of index `B` by values from index `A`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

To get `'jt'` only

```
df[df.Label.eq('jt')].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).B.unique()

Out[22]:
A
unique ID1    [0, 1]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

To get `'edu'` only

```
df[df.Label.eq('edu')].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).B.unique()

Out[23]:
A
unique ID3    [2, 3]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks !

Comment: @AmithAdiraju: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can achive this by using groupby like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['unique ID1', '0', 'Sample sentence 1', 'jt'], ['unique ID1', '1', 'Sample sentence 2', 'jt'], ['unique ID3', '2', 'Sample sentence 3', 'edu'], ['unique ID3', '3', 'Sample sentence 4', 'edu']], columns=('A', 'B', 'Sentence', 'Label'))
result = df.groupby(["A", "Label"]).agg({"B":list}).reset_index(level=0)

## you can get result for jt like

result.loc["jt"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To provide better presentation, I expanded a little your data sample:

```
                Sentence Label
A   B                         
ID1 0  Sample sentence 1    jt
    1  Sample sentence 2    jt
ID3 2  Sample sentence 3   edu
    3  Sample sentence 4   edu
ID4 4  Sample sentence 5    jt
    5  Sample sentence 6    jt
ID5 6  Sample sentence 7   edu
    7  Sample sentence 8   edu
```

The aim was to have at least 2 different *ID*s for each *Label*.

To compute the result for all *Label*s and *ID*s it is enough
to run a single instruction:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['Label', 'A']).B.apply(list)
```

For my data, the result is:

```
Label  A  
edu    ID3    [2, 3]
       ID5    [6, 7]
jt     ID1    [0, 1]
       ID4    [4, 5]
```